# Is it possible to change the account information in Adobe Acrobat DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, sign-out

I installed  Adobe Acrobat DC and mistakenly connected with some account that doesn't have an Adobe Acrobat DC subscription:

[image]

I have another account that does have an Adobe Acrobat DC subscription. Is it possible to change the account information? I tried to reinstall Adobe Acrobat DC but it is still connected to my wrong account.

Comment: Try logging into the account page as that is where you can change the account. If continued issues because the wrong account will not allow you to change then call Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to sign out (red rectangles indicate where one should click):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this with my own Adobe Acrobat DC.  Open your account page if you can, and anywhere you can, and try Get Adobe ID and then sign in again. You may need to contact Adobe support but the above should work.

Comment: Thanks, is the account page somewhere in the Acrobat program? If so, I can't access it, as unless I start the free trial, Acrobat closes right after displaying the popup to shown in the question :/

Comment: Go to Adobe.com and try logging in from the Web Site. That works as well. Ultimately, because of the Account error, Support may have to fix it (and they will)

Comment: Thank you, I have just tried that but it didn't work. I will contact the technical support.

Answer (score 0):

The one and only way to log out of Adobe DC Pro when you have signed in with the wrong account or it's forcing you to try the trial when all you want to do is sign in using a license you already have access to is to go to Adobe Account (https://account.adobe.com). Once you log in there with the account you did not mean to use you'll see Your Plans. Where you see "Adobe Acrobat Pro" you'll see an option to show your Activated Devices. Click on that option and select to remove the device shown. This breaks the link between Adobe DC and the computer you removed. Also if you did try subscribing to the trial you'll be able to cancel that too by going to Manage Plan and selecting Cancel Your Plan. Once you've broken that link though you're all set. The computer you want to use Adobe DC on via use of a license you already had will now work using the license tied to your computer. (Most likely a corporate license)

[Adobe activated devices screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn6PR.png)
[Adobe Your Plans screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXIhv.png)
[Adobe Account screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRpZt.png)